# How to use multiple versions of jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

There are other answers on Stack Overflow however, I can't get any of them to work.

I need to use 2 versions of jQuery. Here is my code:

I link to first version then have this code:

```
 <script>
 var $i = jQuery.noConflict();
 </script>
```

I then link to the 2nd version and have this code:

```
 <script>
 var $j = jQuery.noConflict();
 </script>
```

Here is the code I need to run with the 2nd version $j

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    $j.ready(function() {


        $j('#slider').layerSlider({
            sliderVersion: '6.2.1',
            type: 'fullsize',
            responsiveUnder: 0,
            fullSizeMode: 'hero',
            maxRatio: 1,
            parallaxScrollReverse: true,
            hideUnder: 0,
            hideOver: 100000,
            skin: 'outline',
            showBarTimer: true,
            showCircleTimer: false,
            thumbnailNavigation: 'disabled',
            allowRestartOnResize: true,
            skinsPath: 'skins/',
            height: 800
        });
    });

</script>
```

I inspected the page in Chrome and not showing any errors but it will not run the slider at all.

Comment: Why are you convinced that you need to use 2 versions of jQuery?

Comment: Because this script does not work with v1.12.4 for some reason it needs v1.10.0 and i need v1.12.4 for other stuff i do on the page.

Comment: You do not need to use two versions of jQuery, you really should put the time into consolidating to 1 version of jQuery

Answer (score 1):

Here's one way to load (and use) 2 versions of jQuery at once.  There's no need to call `.noConflict` at all.

```js
console.log(jQuery3.fn.jquery);
console.log(jQuery2.fn.jquery);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>var jQuery3 = jQuery;</script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>var jQuery2 = jQuery;</script>
```

Then to run your slider script with `jQuery2`:

```
$jQuery2.ready(function() {
    $jQuery2('#slider').layerSlider({
        sliderVersion: '6.2.1',
        type: 'fullsize',
        responsiveUnder: 0,
        fullSizeMode: 'hero',
        maxRatio: 1,
        parallaxScrollReverse: true,
        hideUnder: 0,
        hideOver: 100000,
        skin: 'outline',
        showBarTimer: true,
        showCircleTimer: false,
        thumbnailNavigation: 'disabled',
        allowRestartOnResize: true,
        skinsPath: 'skins/',
        height: 800
    });
});
```

Comment: Thank you for that, however, how do I make it run the script? 

$jQuery2.ready(function() {


        $jQuery2('#slider').layerSlider({